# tcl to add numbers in columns till pattern mismatches

Tags: tcl

Hi I need to add numbers in a column till pattern matches and then to start adding numbers after pattern matches, for example:

```
start 1   
start 2  
start 3  
pattern  
start 4    
start 5    
start 6
```

I need to have sum as 6 till pattern and 15 after pattern separately, i tried regexp start but it adds all the numbers in 2nd column irrespective of 'pattern', i know sed works, but i need in tcl-regexp only

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: set sum 0  
set ind [list]  
set skip true  

while {![eof $file]} {  
gets $file $x  
if {[regexp start $x] } {  
set ind [lindex $x 1]  
set sum [expr $sum + $ind]  
set skip "false"  
}   
if {[regexp pattern]} {   
set skip "true"  
}  
}
puts $sum

Comment: I've noticed that you have been posting several questions up to now without really showing the code you are using. I would encourage you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which explains how to ask on StackOverflow. Please put the code in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

With minimal change to your current code and your current attempt/method to reach the desired outcome, this is what I suggest:

```
set sum1 0
set sum2 0
set ind 0
set skip true

while {![eof $file]} {
  # Notice the change of $x to x here
  gets $file x
  if {[regexp start $x]} {
    set ind [lindex $x 1]
    # Depending on $skip, add the number to either sum1 or sum2
    if {$skip == "true"} {
      set sum1 [expr $sum1 + $ind]
    } else {
      set sum2 [expr $sum2 + $ind]
    }
  }
  if {[regexp pattern $x]} {
    set skip "false"
  }
}

puts $sum1
puts $sum2
```

Though, I would use the following to make things a bit simpler:

```
set sum 0

while {[gets $file x] != -1} {
  # if there line has "pattern, then simply print the current sum, then resets it to zero
  if {[regexp pattern $x]} {
    puts $sum
    set sum 0
  } elseif {[regexp {start ([0-9]+)} $x - number]} {
    # if the line matches 'start' followed by <space> and a number, save that number and add it to the sum
    # also, I prefer using incr here than expr. If you do want to use expr, brace your expression [expr {$sum+$ind}]
    incr sum $number
  }
}

# puts the sum
puts $sum
```

Comment: Thanks, here in your code if you change skip to 'false' (in last loop), i am getting desired output

Comment: @johnny thanks, I didn't get to test the code before posting it. Goes to show how hard it can be to predict the outcome the more variables you use!